# Spring4d Event Driven Architecture or How to retrieve all instances of a given interface

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I checked the sample in the Spring4d library on event driven architecture.

From what I can understand, when an event is published, the `ServiceLocator` will instantiate all classes that implement the `IEventHandler<TEventClass>` interface and ask these handlers to handle the event.

Though, is there a recommended approach to only ask already instantiated services to handle the event.

Let's say I have an arbitrary number of `Controllers` that are instanciated. Some of them may be the same class that is instantiated multiple times. Some of them might be unique.

I want these instantiated `Controllers` to listen to a `TUserAdded` event. These `Controllers` implement the `IEventHandler<TUserAdded>` interface. I don't want the non-instantiated `Controllers` to listen to the event.

In a way, I would like to get a list of all instances that implement the `IEventHandler<TUserAdded>` event.

Also, in the ideal case, if a `Controller` is registered as a `Singleton`

```
container.RegisterType<TMySingletonController>.AsSingleton;
```

I would like to instantiate the `TMySingletonController` if it is not already instantiated, then, let it handle the event.

Is there a built-in approach in Spring4d to get a list of all instances of a given interface ?

Comment: Surely you are expected to keep track of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DI container of Spring4D is a so called non tracking container which means it does not track the lifetimes of the instances it creates (except singleton ones of course).

If you want to resolve all registered services for an interface `X` then you can resolve `TArray<X>` or `IEnumerable<X>` but it will create new instances if they are not registered as singleton.

The sample you looked at was taken from a blog article about combining DI and event driven architecture but your problem more sounds like you need to use the observer and factory patterns. Just please don't abuse the DI container as instance repository.